# Windows cmd jq on a curl response not working

Tags: curl, jq

I am basically running this command:

```
curl --request POST --form "file=@tag.txt" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/uploads?private_token=<myToken> | jq .markdown
```

The response I get from the curl looks like this:

```
{"alt":"tag.txt","url":"/uploads/16467a94cf5ea64f4b4541105d03ceaf/tag.txt","markdown":"[tag.txt](/uploads/16467a94cf5ea64f4b4541105d03ceaf/tag.txt)"}
```

I am basically able to run this on a normal GET request - however when I try to jq on this response it fails with the follow error:

**jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:**

Any help is appreciated I am calling these in cmd.exe in windows 7.  I also tried adding '.' but still have the same issue.

-MrShawn

Comment: Please try `.. | jq ".markdown"`

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I get the same error.  ... at , line 1: jq .markdown

Comment: @MrShawn this should work. Can you try quoting the URL for curl? The jq filter is so simple that it shouldn't require any quoting. Also check if all your whitespace are correct.